# Vitest & Vue-Test-Utils Testing Function

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils, vitest

I want to test that the function is called in a simple project.

For this, I read the documentation of [Vitest - Function](https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#functions) and tried to write test as below.

However, I keep getting an error that the function was not called.

**Example.vue**

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const example = () => console.log("TEST");
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <button data-testid="button-example" @click="example">Click</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

**example.spec.ts**

```js
import { describe, vi, it, beforeEach, expect } from "vitest";
import { mount, VueWrapper } from "@vue/test-utils";

import Example from "../src/components/Example.vue";

describe("example testing", () => {
  let wrapper: VueWrapper<Example & { [key: string]: any }>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(Example);
  });

  it("component mounted", () => {
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("example function should be called", async () => {
    const example = vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, "example");
    await wrapper.find('[data-testid="button-example"]').trigger("click");

    expect(example).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

And I get the following error.

```
FAIL  test/example.spec.ts > example testing > example function should be called
AssertionError: expected "example" to be called at least once
 ❯ test/example.spec.ts:21:21
     19|     await wrapper.find('[data-testid="button-example"]').trigger("click");
     20| 
     21|     expect(example).toHaveBeenCalled();
       |                     ^
     22|   });
     23| });
```

**Methods I have tried.**

```js
it("example function should be called", async () => {
  await wrapper.find('[data-testid="button-example"]').trigger("click");
  const example = vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, "example");

  expect(example).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

```js
it("example function should be called", async () => {
  await wrapper.find('[data-testid="button-example"]').trigger("click");

  expect(wrapper.vm.example).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

But when I do as above "*This function is not spy or call spy!*" I get an error.

I think I need to test this function because it looks untested in the coverage report.

Comment: The problem come from the async call.  Your test finished before the return.  Must user done() to fix.